# Why is Kumkuma Puvvu titled as such?

Tags: title, kumkuma-puvvu

*Kumkuma Puvvu* is a Telugu daily Soap Opera telecast on [Star Maa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Maa). It is about a girl Amrutha who is an illegitimate child who was separated from her mother at the time of her birth. She is prone to many struggles in her life and reunites with her parents.

The word Kumkuma Puvvu means [Saffron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saffron), a spice looking like delicate thread. Image below)

[image: Image of Saffron also called as Kashmiri Kesar]

Why is the serial titled as Kumkuma Puvvu? What is the relation between the word and the concept of the show? I ask because all the other daily serials streaming on the channel are either named after characters or by the story lines. This doesn't seem to be either.

Comment: maybe not related, but there was a Saffron in Firefly which illustrated as one girl against the world, lived by her own rules and not having anybody for her.